# Make table row scrollable CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I'm trying to create a table using HTML+Bootstrap CSS with Angularjs framework where if the table data reaches the end of the row, then create a horizontal scrollbar. Each row should take up exactly 1 line. How do I do this?

If I add css style onto the td element for currItem and play around with width and height, I can get it the way I want, but it depends on the screen size. Is there a way to do it to satisfy any size browser window?
    `style="width:200px; height: 50px;display: block; overflow-x: scroll;`

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr ng-repeat="currItem in allItems">
      <td>{{currItem}}</td>
      <td><hr style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need it to be `overflow-x` just make it `overflow: scroll;`. Just do this in the td element. Also, the content has to be long enough to scroll the element.

Comment: Still having the same problem with the same style with overflow:scroll

Comment: @user3125693 I edited my answer and added more to it.

Comment: So you're saying add `style="width:1000px; display: block; overflow: scroll;"` to the td element if i'm understanding correctly? It's still wrapping to a new line  after the line gets to 1000px.

Comment: It doesn't work. It's still wrapping to a new line after the line gets to 1000 px rather than creating a scrollbar on the td element.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer through trial and error... The key was white-space:nowrap

```
        <td style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: scroll;">stuffhere</td>
```